# Erro ao desserealizar JSON: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var des = await JsonSerializer.DeserealizeAsync<IEnumerable<WorkingDaysDates>>(stream);
```

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RefDate3Before "]
public DateTime RefDate3Before { get; set;}
```

Porém quando vou testá-lo, retorna o erro: 
 The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: Inclua seu JSON

Comment: Sem ver o JSON e a estrutura do `WorkingDaysDates` não tem como advinhar a causa do erro... apresente um [MCVE]

Comment: @JuanSantos Resolveu ou desistiu?